# Cannot use Streamlit app due to SSL certificate error

Tags: python, ssl, https, streamlit

I built an app using Streamlit (on Mac) which uses data from Yahoo Finance and I'm trying to run it locally. It was working fine last week, but now when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /quote/SLY (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

This is also preventing me from installing packages as well, so it is completely halting my project progress. I can't do anything until this is solved.

'I have never really developed an app before, so I have no idea what to do in this situation (I'm really a noob in this area so please forgive my ignorance). I have tried researching this problem online and believe I need to "add a certificate" to my list of certificates but don't understand how to do that. I am not using "requests" in my code. In fact, my code is literally just a simple script in VScode that I run in my terminal with `streamlit run myapp.py`. I have thought about just disabling SSL certification, but apparently that is a bad idea (I don't even understand how to do that anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to show the steps generally, if you have problems feel free to ask.

**Step 1:**
Obtaining an SSL certificate.

You can purchase one easily from any trusted website.

**Step 2:**
Install the SSL certificate on your server.

The exact steps for doing this will depend on your hosting environment and the type of certificate you have. But do not fear most of them have a guide to how to add them

For example if you only want to use it in local I believe there is a trick such as [this example](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-run-streamlit-in-https-mode/18426/7?u=arjendeniz)

**Step 3:**
Configure your Streamlit app to use the SSL certificate.

In the `.streamlit/config.toml file`, add the following lines:

```
[server]
enableCORS = false
headless = true
port = 8080
enableXsrfProtection = true
certfile = /path/to/certificate.crt
keyfile = /path/to/privatekey.key
```

(I wrote *path* but those should be the path to given files)

Comment: Can I get an SSL certificate for free using something like Lets Encrypt? I do not really want to pay for one. Also, just to clarify: I am building/using this web app locally on my computer, but the end goal is to deploy this on the web so that anyone can use it. Will I still have the same SSL error then, or would your solution fix this?

Comment: Yeah, you can use one free from the likes of Lets Encrypt & also you would not have the ssl error after deployment