# Problem using streamlit, Windows 10 and Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, ssl, pycharm, streamlit

I am new to Python and pretty much every other programming language. I have extremely simple code,

```
import streamlit as st
st.title("My To-Do App")
```

but when I try to run it using
`C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1>streamlit run C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\main.py`
I have this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1>streamlit run C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\cli.py", line 25, in <module>
    import streamlit.web.bootstrap as bootstrap
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\bootstrap.py", line 31, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.server import Server, server_address_is_unix_socket, server_util
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\server\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.server.component_request_handler import ComponentRequestHandler
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\server\component_request_handler.py", line 18, in <module>
    import tornado.web
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 91, in <module>
    from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 35, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 771, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 592, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 584, in _load_windows_store_certs
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: not enough data: cadata does not contain a certificate (_ssl.c:3989)

(venv) C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1>pip install streamlit==1.14.0                       
Collecting streamlit==1.14.0
  Downloading streamlit-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9.2/9.2 MB 9.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: validators>=0.2 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.0.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow>=4.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (10.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pympler>=0.9 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<4,>=3.12 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (3.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.21.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.10.0.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools>=4.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal>=1.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pydeck>=0.1.dev5 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altair>=3.2.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=1.4 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (6.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=5.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: semver in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rich>=10.11.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (13.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gitpython!=3.1.19 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (3.1.30)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from streamlit==1.14.0) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (4.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from gitpython!=3.1.19->streamlit==1.14.0) (4.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=1.4->streamlit==1.14.0) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.21.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->streamlit==1.14.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4->streamlit==1.14.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4->streamlit==1.14.0) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4->streamlit==1.14.0) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4->streamlit==1.14.0) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.6.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from rich>=10.11.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (2.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown-it-py<3.0.0,>=2.1.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from rich>=10.11.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from tzlocal>=1.1->streamlit==1.14.0) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz-deprecation-shim in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from tzlocal>=1.1->streamlit==1.14.0) (0.1.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from validators>=0.2->streamlit==1.14.0) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap<6,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->gitpython!=3.1.19->streamlit==1.14.0) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.
14.0) (0.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair>=3.2.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (22.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in c:\users\sanja\documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages (from markdown-it-py<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->rich>=10.11.0->streamlit==1.14.0) (0.1.2)
Installing collected packages: streamlit
  Attempting uninstall: streamlit
    Found existing installation: streamlit 1.17.0
    Uninstalling streamlit-1.17.0:
      Successfully uninstalled streamlit-1.17.0
Successfully installed streamlit-1.14.0

(venv) C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1>streamlit run C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\cli.py", line 24, in <module>
    import streamlit.web.bootstrap as bootstrap
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\bootstrap.py", line 31, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.server import Server, server_address_is_unix_socket, server_util
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\server\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.server.component_request_handler import ComponentRequestHandler
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\web\server\component_request_handler.py", line 18, in <module>
    import tornado.web
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 91, in <module>
    from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\Documents\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 35, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 771, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 592, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 584, in _load_windows_store_certs
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: [ASN1] nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4004)
```

I have tried to downgrade streamlit to 1.14.0 as advised somewhere, but didn't help.
Can you please advise, so I can continue my learning process?

I have tried dot downgrade stremline to 1.14.0

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are using a PC with restricted SSL. Will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849236/cannot-use-streamlit-app-due-to-ssl-certificate-error) help?

Comment: can you check if this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303580/error-launching-jupyter-notebook-ssl-sslerror-asn1-nested-asn1-error

Comment: Thnks good people :)

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by removing some software that made confusion from my PC. Happy to continue!